# GNAF query for all points in Turf denoted by list of points?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, australia

I'm using Australia's  gnaf geospatial info which is loaded into postgres with the postgis extension. It is a SQL database . Gnaf has a table of address with long,lat and i have a list of points like , (-1,1) (1,1) (1,0) .... n times .
I need to query for all the points that fall inside the polygon formed by the points.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm that can be used to build the query.?

An example query to extract all points while applying restrictions

`SELECT * FROM Gnaf WHERE longitude > x AND latitude < y`

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code (e.g. SQL) we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  You have a tag for PostGIS but do not mention it in your question, and then you have a mention of Turf in your title but do not tag it or mention it anywhere else.

Comment: Have you got a geometry column in your table, created from the XY values in the GNAF data?  If so, take some time reading up on ST_Extent

Comment: from what i've read and understood ST_Extent return a bounding box if passed in list of geometries. is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem of getting all points inside a Turf(polygon)

`SELECT *
    FROM gnaf_201611.column_name as g
    WHERE ST_Contains(
    ST_GeomFromEWKT('POLYGON((140 -32, 158 -32, 140 -45,  158 -45, 140 -32))'),
                   ST_MakePoint(g.longitude,g.latitude))
    LIMIT 100`

1. ST_Contains takes in two args and returns a boolean (T/F) -> first one is the container and second one is the geometry that we need to check if it is contained by the first one.
2. ST_GeomFromEWKT means Geometry from well known Text , as it says it takes in a string of points and turns it into a geometry. ( For Postgis remember that the it should be a complete closed polygon that means the first point and last point in the text string must be same )
3. ST_MakePoint takes in lat,lon and converts it into geometry for Postgis.

Now we are selecting the data where The polygon contains the point.

**UPDATE**
for more info refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509690/how-to-convert-point-text-to-geometry)

Answer (score 2):

I had a old G-NAF database hanging around which was loaded into a PG database using OGR2OGR.EXE (GDAL utility) from a TAB file.

This query took 39 secs to run and and returned 216K rows. Maybe the polygon is a bit big. The SRID comes from the View named 'geometry_columns', without it PG reports something about incompatible SRID's.

```
SELECT *
  FROM public.gnaf_nsw g
  WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=900916;POLYGON((151 -32, 152 -32, 152 -33, 151 -33, 151 -32))'),g.wkb_geometry)
```

Comment: That definitely helped me a lot.